# How to read images from an api into WPF as a live video play back?

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I am using an api where I can request each frame of a video.
I am trying to load all frames into my c# app and play it back as a video and be able to scrub through each frame.

I was wondering if there is a suitable library that would make this much faster and efficient.

I have tried loading all 1500 frames into a folder then reading them back into my app, but the downloading of the images takes too long before am able to play the video.

WPF:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"/>

<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Play" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Pause" Command="{Binding StopCommand}"/>

    <Slider Name="mcSlider" Width="234" Height="20"  
            Background="Gray" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" Margin="0,2,0,1" Value="{Binding ImageIndex}">
    </Slider>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
void Play()
{
    timer = new SmartDispatcherTimer()
    {
        IsReentrant = false,
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1f / 120f),
        TickTask = async () => { await PlayBack(); }
    };

    timer.Start();
}

private async Task PlayBack()
{
    NextFrame();

    await GetData("54000", _imageIndex, _entry, _imageIndex);
    var fullFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\preview\output" + _imageIndex + ".jpg";

    //Create a new bitmap to assign our image to
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
    bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(fullFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bitmap.EndInit();

    ImagesArray.Add(bitmap);
}
```

The code above is what I am currently trying but the downloading to of each frame is not keeping up with the demand of the playback.

Is there a Library to make my video player runs smoothly?

Comment: Do you write each frame to an intermediate file? Why don't you create a BitmapImage or BitmapFrame directly from a frame buffer in a byte array? Anyway, even then it may only work if each frame is small enough and the frame rate is not too high. Whatever small and high really means here...

Comment: WPF is not suitable for such kind of things. You will need to use the native GDI+ or event better DirectX capabilities to ensure a smooth workflow.

Comment: @Clemens All I am doing at the moment is saving the images in a folder called "preview" in my debug folder I have briefly researched what `IDoc` is, I have never came across the term intermediate file before so I will look further into the benefits of it.

Comment: @dymanoid Why is Wpf not suitable is it because I would have to use C# or VB? Because you said "or even better with direct X" that caught my attention so I have been researching and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43966811) answer. Are you suggesting to use a lower level language such as C++. or I can use C# with Winform instead of WPF?

Comment: All I wanted to say is that you should not write a file at all.